# What is wrong with my PHP/SQL registration script?

Tags: php, sql, authentication, registration, login-script

I'm trying to make my first registration script using PHP/SQL. Part of my code isn't working:

```
if(!$errors){

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES ($registerEmail, $registerPassword)";

    if(mysqli_query($dbSelected, $query)){
        $success['register'] = 'Successfully registered.';
    }else{
        $errors['register'] = 'Registration did not succeed.';
    }
    }
```

When I test my code I get the error 'Registration did not succeed.' For reference, $errors and $success are arrays. Is there anything wrong with this part of my script?

$dbSelected is:

```
    $dbLink = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'PASSWORD');
    if (!$dbLink) {
        die('Can\'t connect to the database: ' . \mysqli_error());
    }

    $dbSelected = mysqli_select_db($dbLink, 'devDatabase');
    if (!$dbSelected) {
        die('Connected database, but cannot select
            devDatabase: ' . \mysqli_error());
    }
```

I'm sure I am connecting and selecting the database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am very new to PHP/SQL so forgive me for any noob mistakes.

Comment: strings need to be quoted

Comment: There is somthing wrong with your mysqli_query

Comment: Hahaha. At this point, you should change your password @Sojourn. Anyone can view previous edits.

Answer (score 0):

Quote the string like below

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES ('$registerEmail', '$registerPassword')";
```

You can also do

```
echo $query;
```

and take the output on the browser, copy and paste into PHPMyAdmin and execute it from there. It should tell you what is wrong with the query.

I suggest you to use prepared statement as using string concatenation in SQL Statement is prone to SQL injection attack. Refer the example [PHP mysqli prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Answer (score -1):

First off, PHP is deprecating mysql_ functions, you should migrate to PDO instead.

Also, make sure since you're using the older mysql_ functions to sanitize your entries using `mysql_real_escape_string`

Also, your entries need to be quoted. Here's a redo of your query string:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES ('{$registerEmail}', '{$registerPassword}')";
```

Comment: hes using mysqli and the {} do nothing here

Comment: No, but it looks nice to me. It's how I place in variables into double quoted strings. As far as I'm aware, even the mysqli_ functions are being deprecated as well.

Comment: "looks nice" ? ok strange. where does the manual (or any source) say mysqli_ is deprecated?

Comment: Yes, looks nice. I have my preference for coding, as you'll have yours. As for deprecation, here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysqli.php List of deprecated mysqli functions.

Comment: that's specific functions NOT mysqli. and {} have a purpose, your using them wrong that's not a style choose

Comment: I'm aware of it's purpose.